# regex excluding newline

Tags: regex, python-3.6

I have a simple word counter that works with one exception.  It is splitting on the \n character.

The small sample text file is:

```
'''
A tree is a woody perennial plant,typically with branches.
I added this second line,just to add eleven more words.
'''
```

Line #1 has ten words, line #2 has eleven.  Total word count = 21.

This code yields a count of 22 because it is including the \n character at the end of line #1:

```
import re


testfile = "d:\\python\\workbook\\words2.txt"

number_of_words = 0

with open(testfile, "r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        number_of_words += len(re.split(",|\s", line))

print(number_of_words)
```

If I change my regex to: number_of_words += len(re.split(",|^\n|\s", line))
the word count (22) remains unchanged.

My question is:  why is exclude newline [^\n] failing, or more broadly, what
should be the correct way to code my regex so that I exclude the trailing \n and have the above code arrive at the correct word total of 21.

Comment: You have a match at the beginning and end of string, thus, there are empty elements in the resulting list at its start and end. Trim the string first. Or use `len(re.findall(r'\S+', line))`. To literally count "words", not punctuation or symbols, you may use `re.findall(r'\w+', line)` or its other variations supporting apostrophes/hyphens. See [this](https://ideone.com/5hSJ4q)

Comment: This did the trick (at least in keeping with what I was trying to accomplish): number_of_words += len(re.split("^[^',],|\s", line))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
number_of_words = 0
with open(testfile, "r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        number_of_words += len(re.findall('\w+', line)
```

Comment: You were excluding cases that most often leads to unexpected result, while this solution only includes what you intended to count.